# SingleLiveEvent issue after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio, android-livedata

After migration to AndroidX by using Android studio 3.2.1 I cannot run app due to this error:

```
SingleLiveEvent.java:29: error: name clash: observe(LifecycleOwner,Observer<T#1>) in SingleLiveEvent and observe(LifecycleOwner,Observer<? super T#2>) in LiveData have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public void observe(LifecycleOwner owner, final Observer<T> observer) {
                ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class SingleLiveEvent
    T#2 extends Object declared in class LiveData
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I googled it, and found solutions for other things, but how to solve this elegantly? I don't want to refactor whole app in every place I use single live event.

Answer (score 28):

I have found the issue.
LiveData provides this:

```
public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer)
```

while SingleLiveEvent provides:

```
public void observe(LifecycleOwner owner, final Observer<T> observer)
```

The solution is to change the method signature in SingleLiveEvent to match LiveData

Comment: the observe method in SingleLiveEvent is overriding the observe method in LiveData, but the erasure in the 2nd parameter does not match. One is Observer<? super T>. Other is Observer<T>

Comment: Help me more in understanding this, Stuck in same issue

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this solution in Kotlin:

`override fun observe(@NonNull owner: LifecycleOwner, @NonNull observer:Observer<in T>)`

Comment: Can you add some explaination?

Comment: While migrating to androidX, I faced this issue. As my SingleLiveEvent class is in Kotlin, the _observe_ function should be like this in Kotlin : `override fun observe(@NonNull owner: LifecycleOwner, @NonNull observer:Observer<in T>) `